# Spring boot Rest Controller POST multiple data types mapped to one request url

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup an endpoint that can accept either a single object or a list of objects of the same type.

I've tried having two methods declared with the two data types but Spring doesn't like that (fails to start server)

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "",
        method = RequestMethod.POST ,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<Object> single(@RequestBody Something something){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = "",
        method = RequestMethod.POST ,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<Object> multiple(@RequestBody List<Something> somethingList){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```

The closest i've gotten is accepting a Something[] and having one method declared.

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "",
        method = RequestMethod.POST ,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<Object> somethingArray(@RequestBody Something... something){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to do this without having to accept just an Object and do the deserialization manually?

EDIT: I  also tried multiple @RequestBody's, ie

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "",
        method = RequestMethod.POST ,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<Object> somethingArray(@RequestBody(required = false) Something something, @RequestBody(required = false) Something[] somethingArray){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a one method, that receive an String for example. Then you need to analyze a String, marshal it to an Object, and call a private method, dependent on result type.
But i mean its wrong approach. Better define different endpoints for different parameters.

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to get around doing that. But i'll have to go down that road as a last resort.

Comment: I think, there is no one good solution.
A resource is uniquely defined by its path, and not by its params. 
Then, rigth decision in your situation is using different url path for each parameter type

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a plural endpoint when doing this.

If I am adding a Customer the endpoint would be /customer,  if it is a List I do /customers.

To my knowledge you cannot overload the request method by parameter type.